# Google Tag Manager for WordPress Accessibility

Tags: wordpress, css, accessibility, google-tag-manager, wcag

I am currently using the Google Tag Manager for WordPress plugin in Wordpress. There are major concerns toward complying with the WCAG 2.0 accessibility guidelines.
Apparently Google Tag Manager for WordPress is placing additional "style" tags within the site code which is, according to the standard, not allowed.
Is there a way to remedy this without ignoring the standard?

Comment: >"Google Tag Manager for WordPress is placing additional "style" tags within the site code which is, according to the standard, not allowed."  What standard are you talking about?  WCAG is the guideline for accessibility and it says nothing about using style tags.  What is your "major concern" for accessibility?

Comment: Hi Jim. Did one of the given answers help you figure out the issue?

Comment: No. Never got a resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Google Tag Manager itself does not use additional style tags. Either they come with the plugin you are using (if you give a name we can check), in which case you could add the GTM code directly to your templates without a plugin.

Or, more likely, they originate in some tag that is deployed via GTM (GTM is a "container" that allows to inject other tags, which are dynamically injected into the page, and these might themselves load other assets, such as style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they getting inserted by the Simple Social Icons plugin